# Generating File Paths for all files in folder structure

Tags: python-3.x, os.path, pathlib

I wanted to generate URLs for all files in a folder hierarchy

```
for path, folder, files in os.walk("C:/Users/guptamols/Course/tutorials"):
     for names in files:
     print(os.path.join(path,names))
```

**Result:**

```
C:/Users/guptamols/Course/tutorials\ch1\Ass1.txt
C:/Users/guptamols/Course/tutorials\ch1\Ass2.txt
```

I found that these issues can be resolved using the Pathlib module, So i tried:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path, folder, files in os.walk("C:/Users/guptamols/Course/tutorials"):
    for name in files:
        Path.joinpath(path,names)
```

It gives this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_make_child'
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To use `Path.joinpath`, you should construct a `Path` object from `path` first:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

for path, folder, files in os.walk("C:/Users/guptamols/AppliedAI New/tutorials"):
    for name in files:
        p = Path(path)       # p is a Path object
        p = p.joinpath(name) # now we appended name to it
        print(p)
```

When invoked as a method of a `Path` instance, the first argument is that instance: `p.joinpath(name)` above can be alternatively written `Path.joinpath(p, name)`.

Alternatively, you can use `os.path.join`, so that you don't need to construct any `Path` objects at all:

```
import os

for path, folder, files in os.walk("C:/Users/guptamols/AppliedAI New/tutorials"):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

If you then want to convert path separators to the native form, like `pathlib` does by default, you can use `os.path.normpath`.

Comment: Hi, @user14620254, 2nd method results in incorrect slashes..I am on windows system

Comment: The first one works perfectly with all backward slashes.

Comment: Isn't this simply because you put forward slashes in the argument to `os.walk`? I copied that from the question body.

Comment: even if I do this, i get the URLs correctly
e.g. ------------>> for path, folder, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):